# Python PIL create thumbnail image with copyright text

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I would like to create a thumbnail image from a larger image then add copyright information to the bottom of the image in a white box with black text.  I guess the process I need to follow is

1. open original image
2. scale image down to new size (width: 300px, height: relative)
3. extend image canvas size to original size + 50px for copyright info (original image top aligned)
4. write copyright info in box
5. save new image.

But I'm not sure how to do this using python and the python imaging library.

Comment: and which part are you stuck on?

Comment: number 3 mostly.  I have found out how to do the other stuff although all on differnet sites.  I just wondered if there was example out there that combined everything into one

Comment: For number 3, create new image object of desired size, then paste your resized image in there (image.paste() method, details in PIL handbook)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import Image
import ImageDraw

im = Image.open("image.jpg")
im.thumbnail((300,300))
box = im.getbbox()
im2=im.crop((box[0], box[1], box[2], box[3]+50))
draw=ImageDraw.Draw(im2)
draw.text((box[2]-100,box[3]+10), "Copyright")
im2.show()
```

Setting the font and exact sizing left as an exercise to the reader